# Return a tuple with the most common elements from list of lists

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list:

```
list = [{"maamaks kaotada", "pensione tõsta", "kaitsekulutusi tõsta"},
        {"lasteaiaõpetajate palku tõsta", "kindlustada tasuta hambaravi kuni 30-aastastele"},
        {"sisserännet piirata", "pensione tõsta", "kaitsekulutusi tõsta"},
        set()]
```

I need to create a `tuple` ((0, 2) in this case) which has the most common elements. `list` with index 0 and `list` with index 2 have the most common elements, so the tuple must be (0, 2). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already created your list:

```
>>> my_list = [{"maamaks kaotada", "pensione tõsta", "kaitsekulutusi tõsta"},
...         {"lasteaiaõpetajate palku tõsta", "kindlustada tasuta hambaravi kuni 30-aastastele"},
...         {"sisserännet piirata", "pensione tõsta", "kaitsekulutusi tõsta"},
...         set()]
```

After that the first step would be to count the number of occurences of each string:

```
>>> counts = {}
>>> for dict in myList:
...     for key in dict:
...         counts[key] = counts.get(key,0) + 1
...
>>> counts
{'pensione tõsta': 2, 'maamaks kaotada': 1, 'kindlustada tasuta hambaravi kuni 30-aastastele': 1, 'kaitsekulutusi tõsta': 2, 'sisserännet piirata': 1, 'lasteaiaõpetajate palku tõsta': 1}
```

You can now find the number of counts for the most frequent item[s]:

```
>>> frequent_count = max([counts[i] for i in counts])
>>> frequent_count
2
```

and generate a list of the most frequent item[s]:

```
>>> frequent = []
>>> for key in counts:
...     if counts[key] == max([counts[i] for i in counts]):
...         frequent += [key]
...
>>> frequent
['pensione tõsta', 'kaitsekulutusi tõsta']
```

and finally get the list of sets containing any of your most frequent strings:

```
>>> final_list = []
>>> for i in ,y_list:
...     if any(item in i for item in frequent):
...         final_list += [i]
...
>>> tuple(final_list)
({'pensione tõsta', 'maamaks kaotada', 'kaitsekulutusi tõsta'}, {'pensione tõsta', 'kaitsekulutusi tõsta', 'sisserännet piirata'})
```

or if you want the indices:

```
>>> final_list = []
>>> for i in range(len(my_list)):
...     if any(item in my_list[i] for item in frequent):
...         final_list += [i]
...
>>> tuple(final_list)
(0, 2)
```